# Performance issues of second/third/etc factorial program

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having some performance issues with my program that calculates the second, third, fourth, etc. factorial.

ie 11!! is 11*9*7*5*3*1

ie 111!!! is 111*108*105...

I expect an exponential time scaling, but what I'm getting it more aggressive than I expect.
6th factorial takes 0.2 seconds
7th factorial takes 21 seconds
8th factorial takes so long I haven't finished it

I've noticed a little over half the time is taken printing due to the int to string conversion. I've testing counting up while // 10 but that took even longer.

Anything I can do to improve performance?

```
import MyFormatter
import datetime
import math

def first_n_digits(num, n):
    return num // 10 ** (int(math.log(num, 10)) - n + 1)

start = datetime.datetime.now()  

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=MyFormatter.MyFormatter,
    description="Calcs x factorial",
    usage="",
)

parser.add_argument("-n", "--number", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

s = ""
       
for i in range(0, args.number) :
    s = s + "1"
    n = 1

s = int(s)
arr = []

while (s > 0) :
    arr.append(s)
    s -= args.number
    
n = math.prod(arr)
fnd = str(first_n_digits(n,3))  
print("{}.{}{}e{}".format(fnd[0], fnd[1], fnd[2], str(len(str(n))-1)))

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you are trying to hold in memory integers that are massive.  When you are taking whatever level factorial of numbers over 100K you are talking about numbers with near a million digits.

Comment: @JeffH How would this improve performance? How would you suggest to change it?

Comment: Is it part of your task to make the base number bigger each time?  I can't see the value in working with 11, 111, 1111, 11111, etc.  Would it be acceptable to calculate all of these factorials for a fixed number, say 500?

Comment: @JeffH Yes it is. If you want to look into it is was one of the numbers 'written' by Adam Elga during the big number duel.  Erasing a line through half the ones during it. Thus the 6th factorial of 111111 and so on, where it's the nth factorial of a number where the number is n 1s in a row.